# why subreport not appearing when large data

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2008, crystal-reports-2010

I designed a report with 5 sub reports and having 5 parameters.Based on the condition sub report will shows individual or it will shows all sub reports data when 5 parameters are selected.

But the issue is when I select all parameter first sub report get disappeared.ie not displaying. My query is, in crystal is there any possibility of sub report suppressing because of large data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the amount of data is more than would fit on the page where it starts (or on a single page, period), it may be pushing hte whole subreport to the next page.  Look at your settings in format subreport for 'keeptogether' and 'can grow'; also the keeptogether in section expert, and, if you have any, in group expert; and within the subreport, look at section and group keeptogether settings.

Answer (score 0):

There is no possibility that sub report disappears because of huge data. Irrespective of data sub report will be displayed.

Possiblity that sub report doesn't has any data and there is a option to supress when no data, Its just a thought

Comment: if there are any suppress parameters then this may cause a sub-report to disappear